# Error in Parse SDK The request timed out. (Code: 100, Version: 1.15.3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I used Parse SDK in iOS app. I have set .server and .applicationId in configuration object while configuring Parse. Still i get this error consistently. Any leads appreciated. 
I have tried different networks and verified APP_ID and SERVER_URL.
Configuaration code is

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = PARSE_APP_ID;
    configuration.clientKey = PARSE_CLIENT_KEY;
    configuration.server = PARSE_SERVER_URL;
    configuration.networkRetryAttempts = 10;
}]];
```

> [Error]: The request timed out. (Code: 100, Version: 1.15.3)
>     [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 5 after sleeping for 26.320714 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [**this**](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1017) post on `GitHub` it might simply be a temporary network problem.

Change your network (or try reconnecting) and try again.

2. Verify also that `PARSE_APP_ID`, `PARSE_CLIENT_KEY` and `PARSE_SERVER_URL` are correct

Comment: Yes @RaffAI. I have tried diffrent networks and verified App ID and server url too.